# python sqlalchemy iterating through a query and inserting into a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, after I run this query, how can I put the data it returns into a table?

```
thesenutritiontotals = db.session.query(NutritionConsumed.date, 
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.calories),  
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.total_fat_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.saturated_fat_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.polyunsaturated_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.monosaturated_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.omega_3_fatty_acids_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.omega_6_fatty_acids_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.trans_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.cholestrol_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.sodium_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.potassium_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.total_carbs_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.dietry_fiber_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.starch_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.sugars_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.protein_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_a_iu),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_c_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_d_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_e_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_k_mcg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_b_1_mg_thiamin),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_b_2_mg_riboflavin),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_b_3_mg_niacin),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_b_5_mg_pantothenic_acid ),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_b_6_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_b_7_mg_biotin),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.vitamin_b_12_mcg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.choline_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.betaine_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.folate_mcg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.magnesium_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.phosphorus_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.zinc_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.copper_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.manganese_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.selenium_mcg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.calcium_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.iron_mg),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.linoleic_acid_g),
                    func.sum(NutritionConsumed.polyphenols_mg))\
            .group_by(NutritionConsumed.date).all()

        for nutritiontotal in thesenutritiontotals:
            new_nutrition_total_entry = NutritionTotals(
                                            date=nutritiontotal.date.date(), 
                                            calories=nutritiontotal(1),
                                            total_fat_g=nutritiontotal(2),
                                            saturated_fat_g=nutritiontotal(3),
                                            polyunsaturated_g=nutritiontotal(4),
                                            monosaturated_g=nutritiontotal(5),
                                            omega_3_fatty_acids_mg=nutritiontotal(6),
                                            omega_6_fatty_acids_mg=nutritiontotal(7),
                                            trans_g=nutritiontotal(8),
                                            cholestrol_mg=nutritiontotal(9),
                                            sodium_mg=nutritiontotal(10),
                                            potassium_mg=nutritiontotal(11),
                                            total_carbs_g=nutritiontotal(12),
                                            dietry_fiber_g=nutritiontotal(13),
                                            starch_g=nutritiontotal(14),
                                            sugars_g=nutritiontotal(15),
                                            protein_g=nutritiontotal(16),
                                            vitamin_a_iu=nutritiontotal(17),
                                            vitamin_c_mg=nutritiontotal(18),
                                            vitamin_d_mg=nutritiontotal(19),
                                            vitamin_e_mg=nutritiontotal(20),
                                            vitamin_k_mcg=nutritiontotal(21),
                                            vitamin_b_1_mg_thiamin=nutritiontotal(22),
                                            vitamin_b_2_mg_riboflavin=nutritiontotal(23),
                                            vitamin_b_3_mg_niacin=nutritiontotal(24),
                                            vitamin_b_5_mg_pantothenic_acid=nutritiontotal(25),
                                            vitamin_b_6_mg=nutritiontotal(26),
                                            vitamin_b_7_mg_biotin=nutritiontotal(27),
                                            vitamin_b_12_mcg=nutritiontotal(28),
                                            choline_mg=nutritiontotal(29),
                                            betaine_mg=nutritiontotal(30),
                                            folate_mcg=nutritiontotal(31),
                                            magnesium_mg=nutritiontotal(32),
                                            phosphorus_mg=nutritiontotal(33),
                                            zinc_mg=nutritiontotal(34),
                                            copper_mg=nutritiontotal(35),
                                            manganese_mg=nutritiontotal(36),
                                            selenium_mcg=nutritiontotal(37),
                                            calcium_mg=nutritiontotal(38),
                                            iron_mg=nutritiontotal(39),
                                            linoleic_acid_g=nutritiontotal(40),
                                            polyphenols_mg=nutritiontotal(41))
            db.session.add(new_nutrition_total_entry)
            db.session.commit()
```

but I get the error

```
calories=nutritiontotal(1),
TypeError: 'result' object is not callable
```

how can I put the data stored in 'thesenutritiontotals' the table 'nutritiontotal'

Comment: well im learning sqlalchemy and I don't know how else to sum up my data by date and insert it into a new table

Comment: What is the shape of your table? (how many rows how many columns?). Are there any columns that you do not want to use in your sum? Do you want to sum for each of the table columns?

Comment: It looks like you're coming from a language that uses brackets `()` for indexing. In python you'd use `[]`, but as noted in your previous question about this same problem, you should be doing this entirely differently anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58969595/python-sqlalchemy-entering-data-into-table-from-query-object. Also, please edit the existing question about the subject, instead of creating a new question when the previous one was closed as "unclear".

Comment: In 'NutritionConsumed' table theres a few columns I don't sum like 'amount', 'item name' and 'id', everything else needs to get summed by date and then needs to be put into the table 'nutritiontotals'.